# perf tool output, magic values

Tags: arm, perf

I ran perf with the parameter -x to print in machine readable format. The output is as follows:

```
1285831153,,instructions,1323535732,100.00
7332248,,branch-misses,1323535732,100.00
1316.587352,,cpu-clock,1316776510,100.00
1568113343,,cycles,1323535732,100.00
```

the first number is clear but then the values after the descriptions are not clear to me. Is the first one behind the description the runtime? Then why is it different? What does the 100.00 mean at the end of each line? It is not documented; I looked it up here: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Machine_readable_output

Comment: What was your exact `perf stat` command and it options?

Answer (score 1):

`-x` option of stat command is implemented in [`tools/perf/builtin-stat.c` file](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c) as `csv_output` flag, and printing is `static void printout` function "([line 1061](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c#L1061)). Last values in the string are probably from:

```
    print_noise(counter, noise);
    print_running(run, ena);
```

With single run of target program (no `-r 5` or `-r 2` options - https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Repeated_measurement) `print_noise` will not print anything. And `print_running` is printing the "`run`" argument twice, as value and as percentage of `ena`

```
static void print_running(u64 run, u64 ena)
{
    if (csv_output) {
        fprintf(stat_config.output, "%s%" PRIu64 "%s%.2f",
                    csv_sep,
                    run,
                    csv_sep,
                    ena ? 100.0 * run / ena : 100.0);
    } else if (run != ena) {
        fprintf(stat_config.output, "  (%.2f%%)", 100.0 * run / ena);
    }
}
```

You have `run`/`ena` = 1 (100.00%), so theses field have no useful information for you.

They are used in the case of event multiplexing (try `perf stat -d` or `perf stat -dd`; https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#multiplexing_and_scaling_events) when user ask perf to measure more event that can be enabled at same time (8 hardware events on intel with only 7 real hardware counting hardware units). Perf (perf_events subsystem of kernel) will enable some subsets of events and will change these subsets several times per second. Then run/ena will be proportional to the time share when this event was enabled, and run will probably show exact time amount when the event was counted. With normal human-readable perf stat this is marked when there is no `[100%]` for the event line; and the reported event count may be scaled (estimated) for the full running time of the program (inexact scaled).